# Decide if something is a vector space or not

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $ =\mathbb{R}^3$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$ and we define the following operations:
$$(, , ) + (, , ) = (,  + , )$$

$$(, , ) = (, , )$$

Does $V$ over $\mathbb{R}$ with the defined operations is a vector space?

What do I need to check if I want to deduct whether this is a vector pace or not?
Thanks

Comment: See http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/courses/240/06spring/vectorspace.html for a list of definitions and properties that will need to be checked

Answer (score 2):

> What do I need to check if I want to deduct whether this is a vector pace or not

You need to check the *[definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Introduction_and_definition)* of vector spaces.

In your particular case, you don't need to check all the axioms. Note that the new addition defined on $V$ is *not* commutative and thus $V$ with the new addition and the scalar multiplication is not a vector space.